# Powershell for Google Cloud: Authenticate with a service account

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to build an automatic sync solution that uses a Google Cloud storage bucket for storing data.

When I install the cloud SDK it asks for my authentication, but obviously I don't want to use my credentials on the client's server, it should be done with a service account with specific permissions, right?

The documentation just says to authenticate with your credentials. What is the security best practice here?

Comment: Additionally, a doc says to use the JSON by declaring its path in an environment variable, so the authentication is used implicitly. It doesn't work though. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, it's this simple command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=credentials.json
```

And it works! I can upload stuff with PowerShell

The doc is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)